# Where can I find the definition of the WINAPI macro?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2019

As a beginner in C++, I'm building a program in Visual Studio 2019 to create an empty window.

As I understood, the entry point is this:

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

I would like to look into the definition of the `WINAPI` macro, which should be in some included file.

I've tried searching inside `windows.h` but it's not there.

I know that `WINAPI` is an alias for `__stdcall` and that `windows.h` has several `.h` files included.

Comment: The `WINAPI` macro is re-`#defined` in many headers, actually - e.g. `bcrypt.h`, `Vfw.h`, `winbase.inl`, `WinSnmp.h`.

Comment: Why are you so interested in this macro in particular? It really isn't _that_ interesting...

Comment: Use 'Jump to Definition' in VS.  This is what I get: `#define WINAPI __stdcall`.

Comment: And __stdcall sets up the stack frame format (and stack handling) C++ should use when calling into the windows API.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=msvc-170

Comment: @Dai  I would not dismiss curiousity so easily. Details matter or can matter. Even if you   have to look it up only once (and then decice it doesn't matter to your use case) ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I'm not being dismissive of the OP (I'm certainly not discouraging them - I gave them the answer to their question too) - I'm just curious what they're looking for.

Comment: @Dai fair enough :)

Comment: @Dai : When creating a new "empty" VS project for the first time, "wth are all those things" seems like a healthy reaction :)
In this case leading down the path of calling conventions, a good thing to at least have heard about...

Comment: @nick Ah yes, _Calling Conventions_ - not to be confused with the annual gathering of AT&T Professionals

Comment: Question title says "function" but the `WINAPI` macro is not a function, nor a function-like macro, nor a macro that maps to a function name.

Answer (score 1):

Searching in windows.h?

windows.h is just a header includes all necessary headers for a simple final executable, not the entire definition, but *Open Watcom 2.0* contains the header win16.h, _win386.h contains entire definitions.

In [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) (contains all definitions of `WINAPI`, `CALLBACK`, `APIENTRY`):

> This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:
>
> `#define CALLBACK __stdcall`
>
> `CALLBACK`, `WINAPI`, and `APIENTRY` are all used to define functions with the `__stdcall` calling convention. Most functions in the Windows API are declared using `WINAPI`. You may wish to use `CALLBACK` for the callback functions that you implement to help identify the function as a callback function.